# Performance difference: executing stored procedures in SSMS vs calling stored procedure using .NET Windows application

Tags: .net, stored-procedures

I actually have a stored procedure which I use to archive transactional data from our database and transfer them to a DW database in the same server.

When I run the stored procedure in SSMS, it takes around 2-2.5 minutes to complete. However when I tried calling the stored procedure using a windows application (its a batch job), it took around 30 minutes to complete (same parameters).

I was wondering if this is normal because I'm surprised with the time difference.

Thanks!

Comment: are you running it in a transaction? are the two queries at the same isolation-level? is the query using any stored-computed fields (including xml columns) ? (if so, it is very susceptible to the `SET` configuration)

Comment: the stored procedure is using a transaction...

Comment: actually it's they are running the same stored procedure... i just ran it in the SSMS to make sure that the stored procedure is running properly... but when called the stored procedure in my app, its taking it 30 mins to complete

Comment: and have you investigated the various SET options? i.e. which are in play in the two scenarios?

Comment: sorry but im not really familiar with SET options...

Comment: the only SET options that were used are: SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; SET NOCOUNT ON - which, i think, are set by default...

Comment: well, the `NOCOUNT` certainly isn't the default, but I don't think that one will matter. Try specifying those `SET` options explicitly in both places (i.e. in the .NET code too) - does it improve?

Comment: By any chance are you running on a different machine when you run it in SSMS compared to in your app.   In your app it completes with no error?

Comment: Marc - I'll try to check the other SET options... although i think those should matter that much considering that I'm using the same stored procedure...

Comment: Blam - nope... i'm running on the same machine... well, aside from a timeout error i encountered, no errror...

Answer (score 1):

It's because your sql server stored 2 execution plan in its cache. 
When you query something SQL Server does this

- is there any execution plan in the cache with the current settings ?
- if no create one using the provided parameters for guessing the best query plan

Your ado.net client will query with the setting ARITHABORT set to Off and SSMS with this set to On so SQL Server will have 2 execution plan.

If you want to be in the same condition in SSMS and in your code, do this 
Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server  -> Advanced -> uncheck SET ARTHABORT (this parameter is useless).

source : http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html (the best article I've ever read about this)